# Please explain the following code in detail

Tags: c++, reference, constants

```
const int m=10;    
int &n=m;    
n=11;    
cout << m << n;
```

It results in compile time error.

I am just unable to learn this pointer variable. Please explain.

Comment: "It results in compile time error." what does the compiler say? Usually the problem is written right there.

Comment: You want us to explain your own code to you? Also even if it did compile, what you're attempting to do is undefined behavior, so don't.

Comment: There are no pointers in your code, just a reference. And you are trying to modify a `const int` through a non`const` reference. It should be obvious why that won't work.

Comment: `T& variable` declares a variable of type `T&` - T reference. It does not declare a variable of type `T*` which would be a pointer to T.

Comment: Sorry it compiles successfully but with a warning. "temporary used to initialize 'n'. Basically I don't understand this code. someone asked to find out whats the output.

Comment: @Aroona: Who asked you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see why you're having trouble with this pointer variable: *it isn't one*. It is a reference.

You cannot have a non-`const` reference to a `const` thing. That would violate the `const`, and allow the `n = 11` line to succeed, thus again violating the original `const`.

`const` means "I cannot and will not change this thing any more".

For more information, turn to the page in your C++ book about `const`.